# Office js AddIn development in VS 2017 - how to setup the SSL URL

Tags: visual-studio-2017, office-js

I'm developing an excel office-js AddIn in Visual Studio 2017. I use ADAL for user authentication, so I need our administrator to add my development address to the list of Redirect URIs in Azure/App registrations. The problem is, that the URL is somehow created by Visual Studio itself, it changes from time to time (I don't know why and when, but it happens) and I'm not able to figure out how to change it.

[image: This is how it looks in VS]

So I always have to ask our Azure administrator to add new URL. Is there some way how to control this URL by myself?

Thanks

Filip

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those values are stored in the *.csproj (or *.vsproj) file. They should not change on their own, but if they are changing as you say, you can change them back by editing the *proj file in a text editor (with VS closed). Just search the file for the current port number and change it.

Comment: this works, but with a small modification - the *.csproj.user file must be modified (I'm not sure, if only this or both, but if both files are modified, it works). Thanks!